# Get the average attendance?

Tags: subquery

I am trying to develop a subquery to get the average attendance from two tables along with full details

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: Hi @Sunny, you should probably add it to your question, not as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
select EVENTID ,
EVENTNAME ,
STARTDATETIME ,
ENDDATETIME ,
CONCERT_CONCERTID ,
VENUE_VENUEID,COUNT(TIMEOFARRIVAL),AVG(TIMEOFARRIVAL) 
FROM EVENT INNER JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKING.EVENT_EVENTID = EVENT.EVENTID;
```

There is an error inconsistent datatypes expected number got timestamp

Comment: This is my answer, please don't forget to accept my answer if it is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to get the number of attendees per event:

```
SELECT e.eventid, COUNT(b.customer_customerid) AS customer_cnt
  FROM event e LEFT JOIN booking b
    ON e.eventid = b.event_eventid
 GROUP BY e.eventid;
```

Now I use a `LEFT JOIN` above because an event could conceivably have zero attendance and those should be counted as well!

We can get the average using a window function (what Oracle calls an analytic function):

```
SELECT eventid, attendance, AVG(attendance) OVER ( ) AS avg_attendance
  FROM (
    SELECT e.eventid, COUNT(b.customer_customerid) AS attendance
      FROM event e LEFT JOIN booking b
        ON e.eventid = b.event_eventid
     GROUP BY e.eventid
);
```

Now we can get all events with below-average attendance:

```
SELECT eventid, attendance FROM (
    SELECT eventid, attendance, AVG(attendance) OVER ( ) AS avg_attendance
      FROM (
        SELECT e.eventid, COUNT(b.customer_customerid) AS attendance
          FROM event e LEFT JOIN booking b
            ON e.eventid = b.event_eventid
         GROUP BY e.eventid
    )
) WHERE attendance < avg_attendance;
```

The above will give you a list of `eventid`s - you can get the rest of the columns you need by querying the `event` table with this list.

Edited based on comments - poster would like to determine the events *for each concert* with below average attendance for that concert.

```
SELECT concertid, eventid, attendance, avg_attendance FROM (
    SELECT concertid, eventid, attendance, AVG(attendance) OVER ( PARTITION BY concertid ) AS avg_attendance
      FROM (
        SELECT c.concertid, e.eventid, COUNT(b.timeofarrival) AS attendance
          FROM concert c INNER JOIN event e
            ON c.concertid = e.concert_concertid
          LEFT JOIN booking b
            ON e.eventid = b.event_eventid
         GROUP BY e.eventid
    )
) WHERE attendance < avg_attendance;
```

Comment: @Sunny, yes, you can use `timeofarrival` instead of `customer_customerid` in the `COUNT()` function to determine attendance - assuming `timeofarrival` is NULL if the customer doesn't attend.

Comment: @Sunny you did not specify average attendance per concert in your original question, so yes, the average would be the same. I've modified my answer so that the query calculcates average attendance for events at each concert.